# How to have SQL query with 2 subqueries divided

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a database which has these tables:

1. Users (id, email)
2. Trips (id, driver_id)
3. MatchedTrips (id, trip_id)

I need to get **for each user** the total number of trips he created divided by the total matches found.

I am stuck in building the raw SQL query for this. Here is what I tried, and sure it's far from being correct.

```
SELECT
  users.email,
  total_trips.count1 / total_matches.count2
FROM users CROSS JOIN (SELECT
        users.email,
        count(trips.driver_id) AS count1
      FROM trips
        INNER JOIN users ON trips.driver_id = users.id
      GROUP BY users.email) total_trips
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT users.email, count(matches.trip_id) AS count2
                   FROM matches
                   LEFT JOIN trips ON matches.trip_id = trips.id
                   LEFT JOIN users ON trips.driver_id = users.id
                   GROUP BY users.email) total_matches;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use `count(distinct)`:

```
select u.email,
       count(distinct t.id) as num_trips,
       count(distinct m.id) as num_matches,
       (count(distinct t.id) / count(distinct m.id)) as ratio
from users u left join
     trips t
     on t.driver_id = u.id left join
     matches m
     on m.trip_id = t.trip_id
group by u.email;
```

Note:  If emails are unique, then the query can be simplified.  `count(distinct)` can be expensive under some circumstances.

Comment: I think this query needs to handle division by zero case, and yes emails are unique. Thanks Gordon for your help.

Comment: @IslamWazery . . . Your original query doesn't handle that case.  But it is easy enough:  `(count(distinct t.id) / nullif(count(distinct m.id), 0))`.

Comment: thank you, and I accepted your answer as it's really what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate total trips and total matches for each driver in the way like this:

```
select driver_id, count(t.id) as total_trips, count(m.id) as total_matches
from trips t
left join matches m on (t.id = trip_id)
group by 1
```

Use this query as a derived table in join with `users`:

```
select email, total_trips, total_matches, total_trips::dec/ nullif(total_matches, 0) result
from users u
left join (
    select driver_id, count(t.id) as total_trips, count(m.id) as total_matches
    from trips t
    left join matches m on (t.id = trip_id)
    group by 1
    ) s on u.id = driver_id
order by 1;
```

[SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/23ac9/4)